# Traversing with a Biapplicative

Tags: haskell, traversal, bifunctor

I was thinking about unzipping operations and realized that one way to express them is by traversing in a [`Biapplicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html#t:Biapplicative) functor.

```
import Data.Biapplicative

class Traversable2 t where
  traverse2 :: Biapplicative p
            => (a -> p b c) -> t a -> p (t b) (t c)

-- Note: sequence2 :: [(a,b)] -> ([a], [b])
sequence2 :: (Traversable2 t, Biapplicative p)
          => t (p b c) -> p (t b) (t c)
sequence2 = traverse2 id

instance Traversable2 [] where
  traverse2 _ [] = bipure [] []
  traverse2 f (x : xs) = bimap (:) (:) (f x) <<*>> traverse2 f xs
```

It smells to me as though every instance of `Traversable` can be transformed mechanically into an instance of `Traversable2`. But I haven't yet found a way to actually implement `traverse2` using `traverse`, short of converting to and from lists or perhaps playing extremely dirty tricks with `unsafeCoerce`. Is there a nice way to do this?

---

Further evidence that anything `Traversable` is `Traversable2`:

```
class (Functor t, Foldable t) => Traversable2 t where
  traverse2 :: Biapplicative p
            => (a -> p b c) -> t a -> p (t b) (t c)
  default traverse2 ::
               (Biapplicative p, Generic1 t, GTraversable2 (Rep1 t))
            => (a -> p b c) -> t a -> p (t b) (t c)
  traverse2 f xs = bimap to1 to1 $ gtraverse2 f (from1 xs)

class GTraversable2 r where
  gtraverse2 :: Biapplicative p
             => (a -> p b c) -> r a -> p (r b) (r c)

instance GTraversable2 V1 where
  gtraverse2 _ x = bipure (case x of) (case x of)

instance GTraversable2 U1 where
  gtraverse2 _ _ = bipure U1 U1

instance GTraversable2 t => GTraversable2 (M1 i c t) where
  gtraverse2 f (M1 t) = bimap M1 M1 $ gtraverse2 f t

instance (GTraversable2 t, GTraversable2 u) => GTraversable2 (t :*: u) where
  gtraverse2 f (t :*: u) = bimap (:*:) (:*:) (gtraverse2 f t) <<*>> gtraverse2 f u

instance (GTraversable2 t, GTraversable2 u) => GTraversable2 (t :+: u) where
  gtraverse2 f (L1 t) = bimap L1 L1 (gtraverse2 f t)
  gtraverse2 f (R1 t) = bimap R1 R1 (gtraverse2 f t)

instance GTraversable2 (K1 i c) where
  gtraverse2 f (K1 x) = bipure (K1 x) (K1 x)

instance (Traversable2 f, GTraversable2 g) => GTraversable2 (f :.: g) where
  gtraverse2 f (Comp1 x) = bimap Comp1 Comp1 $ traverse2 (gtraverse2 f) x

instance Traversable2 t => GTraversable2 (Rec1 t) where
  gtraverse2 f (Rec1 xs) = bimap Rec1 Rec1 $ traverse2 f xs

instance GTraversable2 Par1 where
  gtraverse2 f (Par1 p) = bimap Par1 Par1 (f p)
```

Comment: Check out Conor McBride's "Clowns to the Left of me, Jokers to the Right: Dissecting Data Structures," if you haven't already. (https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis39903/static/clowns.pdf)

Comment: @Davislor, I think that relates to an entirely different sort of "unzipping".

Comment: @Davislor, it should be pretty easy to implement `Traversable` using `Traversable2`. Going the other way seems rarer harder.

Comment: Note that `traverse (f :: a -> f b) ([] :: [a]) = pure ([] :: [b])`. This seems like good evidence to me that `traverse` is not enough to implement `traverse2`, since we would therefore need an `Applicative` instance for which `pure ([] :: [b])` called `bipure ([] :: [b]) ([] :: [c])` (arg. 2 (!)) (without knowing anything special about lists, since the implementation of `traverse` is supposed to be the piece supplying all the list-specific knowledge). IOW, every call to `pure` (and `(<*>)`) gets handed a *monomorphic* thing rather than a *polymorphic* thing, and this prevents goodness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One only mildly evil way to do this is using something like `Magma` from `lens`. This seems considerably simpler than leftaroundabout's solution, although it's not beautiful either.

```
data Mag a b t where
  Pure :: t -> Mag a b t
  Map :: (x -> t) -> Mag a b x -> Mag a b t
  Ap :: Mag a b (t -> u) -> Mag a b t -> Mag a b u
  One :: a -> Mag a b b

instance Functor (Mag a b) where
  fmap = Map

instance Applicative (Mag a b) where
  pure = Pure
  (<*>) = Ap

traverse2 :: forall t a b c f. (Traversable t, Biapplicative f)
          => (a -> f b c) -> t a -> f (t b) (t c)
traverse2 f0 xs0 = go m m
  where
    m :: Mag a x (t x)
    m = traverse One xs0

    go :: forall x y. Mag a b x -> Mag a c y -> f x y
    go (Pure t) (Pure u) = bipure t u
    go (Map f x) (Map g y) = bimap f g (go x y)
    go (Ap fs xs) (Ap gs ys) = go fs gs <<*>> go xs ys
    go (One x) (One y) = f0 x
    go _ _ = error "Impossible"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I might have something that fits your bill. (Edit: It doesn't, see comments.) You can define newtypes over `p () c` and `p b ()` and make them `Functor` instances.

### Implementation

Here's your class again with default definitions. I went the route of implementing `sequence2` in terms of `sequenceA` because it seemed simpler.

```
class Functor t => Traversable2 t where
  {-# MINIMAL traverse2 | sequence2 #-}
  traverse2 :: Biapplicative p => (a -> p b c) -> t a -> p (t b) (t c)
  traverse2 f = sequence2 . fmap f

  sequence2 :: Biapplicative p => t (p b c) -> p (t b) (t c)
  sequence2 = traverse2 id
```

Now, the "right part" of the `Biapplicative` is

```
newtype R p c = R { runR :: p () c }

instance Bifunctor p => Functor (R p) where
  fmap f (R x) = R $ bimap id f x

instance Biapplicative p => Applicative (R p) where
  pure x = R (bipure () x)
  R f <*> R x =
    let f' = biliftA2 const (flip const) (bipure id ()) f
    in  R $ f' <<*>> x

mkR :: Biapplicative p => p b c -> R p c
mkR = R . biliftA2 const (flip const) (bipure () ())

sequenceR :: (Traversable t, Biapplicative p) => t (p b c) -> p () (t c)
sequenceR = runR . sequenceA . fmap mkR
```

with the "left part" much the same. The full code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nnmm/ce88f682d30201b794ce5d17d980d719).

Now we can make `p (t b) ()` and `p () (t c)` and reassemble them into `p (t b) (t c)`.

```
instance (Functor t, Traversable t) => Traversable2 t where
  sequence2 x = biliftA2 const (flip const) (sequenceL x) (sequenceR x)
```

I needed to turn on FlexibleInstances and UndecidableInstances for that instance declaration. Also, somehow ghc wanted a Functor constaint.

### Testing

I verified with your instance for `[]` that it gives the same results:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let xs = [(x, ord x - 97) | x <- ['a'..'g']]
  print xs
  print (sequence2 xs)
  print (sequence2' xs)

traverse2' :: Biapplicative p => (a -> p b c) -> [a] -> p [b] [c]
traverse2' _ [] = bipure [] []
traverse2' f (x : xs) = bimap (:) (:) (f x) <<*>> traverse2 f xs

sequence2' :: Biapplicative p => [p b c] -> p [b] [c]
sequence2' = traverse2' id
```

outputs

```
[('a',0),('b',1),('c',2),('d',3),('e',4),('f',5),('g',6)]
("abcdefg",[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
("abcdefg",[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

This was a fun exercise!

Comment: I don't think that works. You traverse the sequence *twice*, which performs each effect twice.

Comment: Do you have an example for that?

Comment: Use a more exciting `Biapplicative`. Try `newtype BIO x y = BIO (IO (x, y))` (that is, `Tannen IO (,)`) and use input and output in your traversal.

Comment: You're right, if I print a '+' everytime, I get a different number of pluses. So I assume this implementation violates some law of `Traverse2`.

Comment: I haven't written laws, but I think the `Traversable` ones should translate. I think your implementation will break the composition law.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to do the trick, exploiting “only” `undefined`. Possibly the traversable laws guarantee that this is ok, but I've not attempted to prove it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, KindSignatures, TupleSections #-}

import Data.Biapplicative

import Data.Traversable

data Bimock :: (* -> * -> *) -> * -> * where
   Bimock :: p a b -> Bimock p (a,b)
   Bimfmap :: ((a,b) -> c) -> p a b -> Bimock p c
   Bimpure :: a -> Bimock p a
   Bimapp :: Bimock p ((a,b) -> c) -> p a b -> Bimock p c

instance Functor (Bimock p) where
  fmap f (Bimock p) = Bimfmap f p
  fmap f (Bimfmap g p) = Bimfmap (f . g) p
  fmap f (Bimpure x) = Bimpure (f x)
  fmap f (Bimapp gs xs) = Bimapp (fmap (f .) gs) xs
instance Biapplicative p => Applicative (Bimock p) where
  pure = Bimpure
  Bimpure f<*>xs = fmap f xs
  fs<*>Bimpure x = fmap ($x) fs
  fs<*>Bimock p = Bimapp fs p
  Bimfmap g h<*>Bimfmap i xs = Bimfmap (\(~(a₁,a₂),~(b₁,b₂)) -> g (a₁,b₁) $ i (a₂, b₂))
                              $ bimap (,) (,) h<<*>>xs
  Bimapp g h<*>xs = fmap uncurry g <*> ((,)<$>Bimock h<*>xs)

runBimock :: Biapplicative p => Bimock p (a,b) -> p a b
runBimock (Bimock p) = p
runBimock (Bimfmap f p) = bimap (fst . f . (,undefined)) (snd . f . (undefined,)) p
runBimock (Bimpure (a,b)) = bipure a b
runBimock (Bimapp (Bimpure f) xs) = runBimock . fmap f $ Bimock xs
runBimock (Bimapp (Bimfmap h g) xs)
     = runBimock . fmap (\(~(a₂,a₁),~(b₂,b₁)) -> h (a₂,b₂) (a₁,b₁))
           . Bimock $ bimap (,) (,) g<<*>>xs
runBimock (Bimapp (Bimapp h g) xs)
     = runBimock . (fmap (\θ (~(a₂,a₁),~(b₂,b₁)) -> θ (a₂,b₂) (a₁,b₁)) h<*>)
           . Bimock $ bimap (,) (,) g<<*>>xs

traverse2 :: (Biapplicative p, Traversable t) => (a -> p b c) -> t a -> p (t b) (t c)
traverse2 f s = runBimock . fmap (\bcs->(fmap fst bcs, fmap snd bcs)) $ traverse (Bimock . f) s


sequence2 :: (Traversable t, Biapplicative p)
          => t (p b c) -> p (t b) (t c)
sequence2 = traverse2 id
```

And even if this is safe, I wouldn't be surprised if it gives horrible performance, what with the irrefutable patterns and quadratic (or even exponential?) tuple-tree buildup.

Comment: Any reason to use `undefined` rather than `()`?

Comment: @Davislor `()` always has type `()`.

Comment: Okay, so it's conceptually similar to nnnmmm’s answer, but instead of defining two types, `R` and `L`, which replace either `a` or `b` with `()`, or what I did for my first unposted solution and required `T a` and `T b` to be `Monoids` so I could use `mempty`, you use `undefined` to work around the type system. Got it.

Comment: I'm guessing it *might* be possible to use the machinery in https://gist.github.com/treeowl/9621f58d55fe0c4f9162be0e074b1b29 to get a more principled and (somewhat) less inefficient implementation. But I don't *think* either approach will help with infinite traversals.

Comment: As long as you're using `undefined`, is there a reason not to do the dead simple thing of using `toList` and then traversing in `State`?

Comment: @dfeuer Does that necessarily preserve the shape of any `Traversable`?

Comment: @Davislor, yes. Where it has trouble is with infinite traversables and lazy applicatives.

Comment: I understand this better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A few observations short of a complete, original answer.

If you have a `Biapplicative` bifunctor, what you can do with it is apply it to something and separate it into a pair of bifunctors isomorphic to its two components.

```
data Helper w a b = Helper {
  left :: w a (),
  right :: w () b
}

runHelper :: forall p a b. Biapplicative p => Helper p a b -> p a b
runHelper x = biliftA2 const (flip const) (left x) (right x)

makeHelper :: (Biapplicative p)
           => p a b -> Helper p a b
makeHelper w = Helper (bimap id (const ()) w)
                      (bimap (const ()) id w)

type Separated w a b = (w a (), w () b)
```

It would be possible to combine the approaches of @nnnmmm and @leftroundabout by applying `fmap (makeHelper . f)` to the structure `s`, eliminating the need for `undefined`, but then you would need to make `Helper` or its replacement an `instance` of some typeclass with the useful operations that let you solve the problem.

If you have a `Traversable` structure, what you can do is `sequenceA` `Applicative` functors (in which case your solution will look like `traverse2 f = fromHelper . sequenceA . fmap (makeHelper . f)`, where your `Applicative` instance builds a pair of `t` structures) or `traverse` it using a `Functor` (in which case your solution will look like `traverse2 f = fromHelper . traverse (g . makeHelper . f) where` ...).  Either way, you need to define a `Functor` instance, since `Applicative` inherits from `Functor`.  You might try to build your `Functor` from `<<*>>` and `bipure id id`, or `bimap`, or you might work on both separated variables in the same pass.

Unfortunately, to make the types work for the `Functor` instance, you have to paramaterize `:: p b c` to a type we would informally call `:: w (b,c)` where the one parameter is the Cartesian product of the two parameters of `p`.  Haskell’s type system doesn’t seem to allow this without non-standard extensions, but @leftroundabout pulls this off ably with the `Bimock` class. using `undefined` to coerce both separated functors to have the same type.

For performance, what you want to do is make no more than one traversal, which produces an object isomorphic to `p (t b) (t c)` that you can then convert (similar to the Naturality law).  You therefore want to implement `traverse2` rather than `sequence2` and define `sequence2` as `traverse2 id`, to avoid traversing twice.  If you separate variables and produce something isomorphic to `(p (t b) (), p () (t c))`, you can then recombine them as @mmmnnn does.

In practical use, I suspect you would want to impose some additional structure on the problem.  Your question kept the components `b` and `c` of the `Bifunctor` completely free, but in practice they will usually be either covariant or contravariant functors that can be sequenced with `biliftA2` or traversed together over a `Bitraversable` rather than `Traversable` `t`, or perhaps even have a `Semigroup`, `Applicative` or `Monad` instance.

A particularly efficient optimization would be if your `p` is isomorphic to a `Monoid` whose `<>` operation produces a data structure isomorphic to your `t`.  (This works for lists and binary trees; `Data.ByteString.Builder` is an algebraic type that has this property.)  In this case, the associativity of the operation lets you transform the structure into either a strict left fold or a lazy right fold.

This was an excellent question, and although I don’t have better code than @leftroundabout for the general case, I learned a lot from working on it.