# Does a joined Bitraversable require Monad?

Tags: haskell, applicative, traversable, foldable

Despite the jargon filled title I don't think this question is very complex.

### Introducing the characters

There are two important Functor combinators at play here. `Flip` equivalent to the haskell functiong `flip` but operating on types

```hs
newtype Flip p a b
  = Flip
    { unFlip :: p b a
    }
```

and `Join` equivalent to the W combinator on types, it takes a bifunctor and produces a functor along both its arguments

```hs
newtype Join p a
  = W
    { unW :: p a a
    }
```

---

### Traversable

Now for `Foldable` it is possible to make the following instance:

```hs
instance
  ( forall a . Foldable (p a)
  , forall a . Foldable (Flip p a)
  )
    => Foldable (Join p) where
  foldr g x (W xs) = foldr g (foldr g x xs) (Flip xs)
```

That is to say if `p` is foldable across both of its arguments then `Join p` is foldable.  This is done by folding across the left and then the right.

Now I would like to make an analogous instance for `Traversable`, however I run into a problem.  I can write `sequence` easily enough

```hs
sequence (W xs) = (map W . join . map (sequenceA . unFlip) . sequenceA . Flip) xs
```

However it seems that I need to be able to use `join` so I am having trouble writing `sequenceA`.  In fact it very much seems impossible to write a `sequenceA`.

However I struggle to come up with a counter example.  That is a `p` which is traversable on two arguments but not traversable when joined.

So far I've tried all the basics but none are counter examples. `Join (,)` is traversable

```hs
sequenceA (W (x, y)) = liftA2 (W . (,)) x y
```

Higher order tuples such as `Join ((,,) a)` are fine.

```hs
sequenceA (W (x, y, z)) = liftA2 (W . (,,) x) y z
```

`Join Either` is also traversable

```hs
sequenceA (W (Left x)) = map (W . Left) x
sequenceA (W (Right x)) = map (W . Right) x
```

I've come up with more examples by composing types around, which I will leave out for simplicity but needless to say they all ended up being traversable.

Is there a counter example?  Can this instance be written?

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but there is more to `Traversable` than you can "prove" in totally legit Haskell. `lens` does some funny business with a type it calls `Magma`. I stole that idea in a slightly different shape to implement `traverseBia` in `Data.Biapplicative`, and you may find that version useful. So even if it's not possible to do it legitimately, you may well be able to do it through the back door.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm certainly not against backdoor methods but I want to make sure that there isn't a counter example before I use one.  I'm not sure I understand what you are meaning when you talk about `traverseBia`.

Comment: I suppose @dfeuer is referring to previous discussions _([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48220977/) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48954495/))_ around `Traversable` where a certain technique was developed of passing through, as I understand, [a free applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Internal-Magma.html), which grants you introspection.